# How to spin up a instance in Jenkins using AWS

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ec2, cloud, jenkins-agent

I have installed ec2 plugin in Jenkins and configured the required fields.
EC2 instances are not getting spinned up.

Jenkins is already installed in AWS instance and I need an agent instance on configuring from Manage Jenkins-->Configure cloud-->Add cloud

Comment: where exactly are you stuck? Do you have all the details to fill in the "configure cloud" are you using ec2 instance profile to spinup new agents from aws?

Comment: yes HumayunM. Ec2 instances are not getting spinned up. Configured everything as told in the video. https://youtu.be/1XI9_4umWVk

Comment: This worked great finally after changing few values for the configurations required.